# Configuring OPTIONS method in API Gateway to return statusCode 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a non-simple cross-origin HTTP request to my POST method in API Gateway.
I have set up CORS support as per : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html
The POST request succeeds from Postman/AWS console but fails from a local development server where the origin is of type localhost.
After browsing through many answers and trying to debug i have concluded that all the required headers are present on the integration response of both POST and OPTIONS. However when making a call to OPTIONS from postman i see that it returns 500 Internal server error. This looks like a configuration issue with OPTIONS. How do i fix it? I don't have a serverless yaml, the gateway has been configured manually. Any way of resolving this via the console ?
[image]

Comment: did you enable cors on the api

Comment: Yes, I did enable CORS on the API.